# Split columns from single table and join as multiple columns on another

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2014, multiple-columns

I want to split a column in 1 table into multiple columns in another table

Let's say I want to join the FoodAttributeTable to the FoodTable:

**FoodTable**

```
+------------+-------+
|    Food    | Price |
+------------+-------+
| Strawberry |    10 |
| Broccoli   |    25 |
+------------+-------+
```

**FoodAttributeTable**

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+
|    Food    | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
+------------+---------------+----------------+
| Strawberry | Vitamin       | C              |
| Strawberry | Weight        | 15g            |
| Strawberry | Color         | Red            |
| Broccoli   | Vitamin       | B              |
| Broccoli   | Weight        | 70g            |
| Broccoli   | Color         | Green          |
+------------+---------------+----------------+
```

*Table to be:*

**FoodTable**

```
+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|    Food    | Price | Vitamin | Weight | Color |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| Strawberry |    10 | C       | 15g    | Red   |
| Broccoli   |    25 | B       | 70g    | Green |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Ideally, however, this isn't the right way for a database design. A single column should only represent 1 thing, not different things, based on the value of a different column.

Comment: HI and welcome to SO. If you can post ddl and sample data along with desired output we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple PIVOT query like below.
Check out official **[MSDN documentation on PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)**.

```
select 
Food,Price,Vitamin,Weight,Color
from
(
    select f.Food,f.Price,
     AttributeName  ,AttributeValue
    from
    FoodTable f join
    FoodAttributeTable fat on
    f.Food=fat.Food
)s
pivot
(max(AttributeValue) for AttributeName in (Vitamin,Weight,Color))
p
```

Also here's a <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/FZCV94530)**</kbd>

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot

Comment: @titatovenaar Thank you for the confirmation! Please accept my reply as correct answer so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Dynamic Pivot Query. Therefore, I would only recommend this if your `FoodAttributeTable` attributes are dynamics.

Create Tables and Insert Data

```
CREATE TABLE FoodAttributeTable(
    Food nvarchar(50) NULL,
    AttributeName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    AttributeValue nvarchar(50) NULL
) 

INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Strawberry', N'Vitamin', N'C')    
INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Strawberry', N'Weight', N'15g')    
INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Strawberry', N'Color', N'Red')    
INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Broccoli', N'Vitamin', N'B')    
INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Broccoli', N'Weight', N'70g')    
INSERT FoodAttributeTable (Food, AttributeName, AttributeValue) VALUES (N'Broccoli', N'Color', N'Green')


CREATE TABLE FoodTable(
    Food nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Price decimal(18, 0) NULL
)

INSERT FoodTable (Food, Price) VALUES (N'Strawberry', N'10')    
INSERT FoodTable (Food, Price) VALUES (N'Broccoli', N'25')
```

Query

```
DECLARE @colsValues AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(fat.attributename)
         FROM   foodattributetable fat       
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) =  'SELECT     * 
                                    FROM       (SELECT * 
                                                FROM   foodattributetable 
                                                PIVOT(Max(attributevalue) 
                                                FOR attributename IN ('+ @colsValues +')) piv) fat
                                    INNER JOIN foodtable tb 
                                    ON         tb.food = fat.food';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Output

```
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+-------+
|    Food    | Color | Vitamin | Weight |    Food    | Price |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+-------+
| Broccoli   | Green | B       | 70g    | Broccoli   |    25 |
| Strawberry | Red   | C       | 15g    | Strawberry |    10 |
+------------+-------+---------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ATZF46215

Comment: I am curious. Because the previous solution works, but probably not dynamic. Sometimes there are new Food or AttributeTypes added. Is this the way to deal with that?

Comment: This is a dynamic PIVOT query. So, yes. I believe so. You can add new food, attributeName, AttributeValue and you don't have to change the query. Demo: http://rextester.com/AVS94472